# How to delete ship in Anno-online?

Tags: anno-online

In the old Anno games ships can be deleted with Delete. But how to do this in Anno Online? I no longer need my delicate discovery ship and it's occupying a ship slot.

Comment: We tend not to use broad tags, just tags for the game in question. I have created the [anno-online] tag now, however, as that is indeed the name of the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Don't know if it still works, but have you tried to press "Del" Key when the ship is selected?

Also, i found this on [Anno Online FAQ](http://us.anno-online.com/en/help-and-support/game-faq)

> **How can I sink a ship?**
>
> You can use the demolish mode that you normally
>   use to demolish buildings to sink ships. It can be activated by
>   left-clicking the pickaxe button in the menu in the lower right
>   corner. You will be given no refund by doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, you can only find the "sink" option when browsing through your discovery ships in the **Ship List**.

[image: And thaaaaaat's how the news goes]